# fetch api in sub component react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React Table and I want to get the ID value of each row and give it to another address and finally give the output to the audio player. But I could not call the api inside the subcomponent

Comment: <ReactTable
    data={api}
    columns={columns}
    defaultPageSize={9}
    SubComponent={
      row=>{
       fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.ir/users'+row.original.id)
       .then(res=>res.json())
       .then(rsl=>{
        <audio controls>
  <source src={rsl.url} type="audio/ogg"/>
  
</audio>
       })

 
      }


    }
/>

Comment: Please share your code and show what you got vs expected.

Comment: I wrote the code in the comment section. I now want to learn the correct api method in the subcomponent and be able to display the data taken in the player.

Comment: Put your code in the question and format it. It makes a huge difference in readability and will get more people to respond. A little formatting goes a long way.